# Spring + Quartz - how to create different triggers for the same job method

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to use Spring Quartz to create a scheduler.
I need, at start up, to create a scheduler and add n jobs, depending on Object I retrieve from DB.

Every object will use the same method, but will have a different trigger and must be specific from every Object. I cannot find a proper way to do this...

this is the job they have to do

```
public class Job {

@Autowired LightService lightService

private void doJob(Light light){

lightService.toggleLight(light);
}

}
```

So, i have a method to retrieve objects

```
List<Light> lights = dao.findLights();
```

and for each `lights` I have to set a `Job` which will have a different Trigger.

Is it possibile?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring wrapped quartz then:

```
//SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFact
Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFact.getObject();
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail,trigger);
```

Autowire `SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFact` and you can use it within any method.

If quartz directly,

```
 //Scheduler scheduler
 scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail,trigger);
```

Create the triggers on the fly and  you can reuse the jobDetail if needed in both cases.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40583086/spring-boot-1-3-3-quartz-2-2-1-trigger-are-not-associated . This question seems to be deleted. I have prepared an answer but not able to post it as it is deleted. I can post the answer if you can undelete it(if needed).

Comment: thanks @prem kumar please find the updated question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594447/spring-quartz-trigger-is-null

Comment: i have worked with quartz for sometime. I think my answer for that deleted post might help you. I am looking into your new question.