# Spring + Quartz, Trigger is null

Tags: java, spring

I'm dwelling with Quartz from days..

I need to create, the app starts, some triggers and job details..

So, this is my Job

```
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class TimeoutJob extends QuartzJobBean{

    public final String ID = "idInterruttore";

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TimeoutJob.class);

    @Autowired InterruttoreService interruttoreService;

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

        JobDataMap dataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
        int idInterruttore = dataMap.getIntFromString(ID);
        Interruttore interruttore = interruttoreService.findById(idInterruttore);
        logger.debug("Job reached for " + interruttore.getNomeInterruttore());

    }
}
```

Then i configure some bean in QuartzConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("it.besmart")
public class QuartzConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler() {
        SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        schedulerFactory.setJobFactory(springBeanJobFactory());
        return schedulerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringBeanJobFactory springBeanJobFactory() {
        AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutoWiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        return jobFactory;
    }
}
```

Now, I have a JobManager.class which manage jobDetails and Triggers

```
@Service("jobManager")
public class JobManager {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JobManager.class);

    @Autowired
    SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler;

    @Autowired
    InterruttoreService interruttoreService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void createInitialJobs() {
        logger.debug("Start ut jobs to create");
        List<Interruttore> interruttori = interruttoreService.findAllSwitches();
        Date now = new Date();
        for (int i = 0; i < interruttori.size(); i++) {
            Interruttore interruttore = interruttori.get(i);
            if (interruttore.getTimeoutDate().after(now) && interruttore.isStato()) { 
                // JobDetail and Trigger creation
                createJob(interruttore, interruttore.getTimeoutDate());
            }
        }

    }

    public void createJob(Interruttore interruttore, Date richiesta) {

        JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetail = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        jobDetail.setJobClass(TimeoutJob.class);
        jobDetail.setName("Job detail for " + interruttore.getNomeInterruttore());
        jobDetail.setDescription("Job Description");
        jobDetail.setDurability(true);

        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        map.put("idInterruttore", interruttore.getIdInterruttore());
        jobDetail.setJobDataAsMap(map);

        long future = richiesta.getTime() - new Date().getTime();
        logger.debug("next timeout is " + future / 1000 / 60 + " minuti for " + interruttore.getNomeInterruttore());

        //trigger creation
        SimpleTriggerFactoryBean trigger = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();
        trigger.setName("myTrigger"+interruttore.getNomeInterruttore());
        trigger.setGroup("timeoutTriggers");
        trigger.setJobDetail(jobDetail.getObject());
        trigger.setStartDelay(0);
        trigger.setRepeatCount(1);
        trigger.setRepeatInterval(future);
        trigger.afterPropertiesSet();
        logger.debug("Trigger for " + interruttore.getNomeInterruttore());
        logger.debug("Trigger object is :" + trigger.getObject());
        logger.debug("Next Trigger date " + trigger.getObject().getFinalFireTime());

        try {
            scheduler.getScheduler().scheduleJob(jobDetail.getObject(), trigger.getObject());
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When launching the app, the `@PostConstruct` method tries to create the triggers, but i'm getting an exception when creating jobManager

```
Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

caused by

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SimpleTriggerFactoryBean.java:231)
    at it.besmart.quartz.JobManager.createJob(JobManager.java:85)
    at it.besmart.quartz.JobManager.createInitialJobs(JobManager.java:54)
```

which is

```
trigger.afterPropertiesSet();
```

as my triggers are not created...

Comment: what is your spring-context-support jar version?

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.3 and spring-context-support 4.2.5

Comment: this version 4.2.5.RELEASE?

Comment: yes, 4.2.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in the spring-context-support jar 4.2.5 version.

```
        sti.setJobKey(this.jobDetail.getKey());
```

i.e. jobDetail can be null.

In the new versions it is fixed. I checked 4.3.2 version.

You can use 4.3.2 or later.

In 4.3.2 version

```
if (this.jobDetail != null) {
        sti.setJobKey(this.jobDetail.getKey());
    }
```

Comment: yes i upgraded all my jars, but i'm getting `org.quartz.SchedulerException: JobDetail cannot be null
 at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.scheduleJob(QuartzScheduler.java:849)
 at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.scheduleJob(StdScheduler.java:249)
 at it.besmart.quartz.JobManager.createJob(JobManager.java:91)
 at it.besmart.quartz.JobManager.createInitialJobs(JobManager.java:54)` which is `scheduler.getScheduler().scheduleJob(jobDetail.getObject(), trigger.getObject());`

Comment: i'm using 4.3.3.RELEASE as version

Comment: you did not call jobDetail.afterPropertiesSet() like you did for trigger

Comment: cool :) .. you're welcome.. are you still having any other questions with quartz?

Comment: now i have to manage the update of triggers dynamically if the timeout changes, if i will have problems i will know who to ask!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128089/discussion-between-prem-kumar-and-besmart).